# How to get Data from belongsTo model in CakePHP 2.9

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to get the details of users from the users table using the ids in another table called virtualwh. The result that displays from the users table is not according to the winners id in the virtualwh.

I created this two tables(Virtualwh and users) and did the association linking using belongsTo (virtualwh => users). On the virtualwh table, there is a column(called winners which is connected to the users table using foreignkey) on each row that stores an id of a single user which is randomly selected and included from another table.  I am trying to get all the ids in the virtualwh and query the Users table for the details of the user with the ids in order to display all their details in a page. This is what I have done but not working. Any help here?

```
/get winnerslist
    $winners = $this->Virtualwarehouse->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Virtualwarehouse.winner !=' => 'null')));
    $winneroptions = array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$winners['Virtualwarehouse']['winner']), array('User.email','User.fname', 'User.path', 'User.pix'));
    $winnersrecord = $this->Virtualwarehouse->User->find('all',$winneroptions);
    $this->set('winnerslist',$winners);
    print_r($winners);
```

users table structure

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `path` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pix` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activation` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `pass_token` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` enum('Female','Male','Others','') DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

virtualwh table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `virtualwh`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virtualwh` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ad_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `alignment` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=top, 2=bottom',
  `image` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `points` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '20',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 = Active, 0 = Inactive',
  `winner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Share the database structure for better understanding.

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah Which version are you using?

Comment: @AmanRawat updated with my table structure.

Comment: @BachchaSingh Cake2.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to belongsto on the fly then use like this

> For cakephp 3.x

```
     $this->Virtualwarehouse->belongsTo('User',[
        'foreignKey' => 'winner',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $winners = $this->Virtualwarehouse->find('all', [
        'contain'=>['User']
    ]);

    $this->set('winnerslist',$winners);
    print_r($winners);
```

> For cakephp 2.x

```
    $this->Virtualwarehouse->bindModel([
        'belongsTo' => [
            'User'=>[
                'foreignKey' => 'winner',
                'type'=>'INNER'
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $winners = $this->Virtualwarehouse->find('all');

    $this->set('winnerslist',$winners);
    print_r($winners);
```

Comment: can I make use of this in the controller without editing the Model because I have a foreign key in the Virtualwarehouse Model that points to users id. If not, any advise on what to do cause I have another foreign key already being pointed to(users.id) from the virtualwarehouse model..

Comment: yes, it is for controller you dont have to put it in model thats why i called on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Try the following codes if you are using CakePhp 3.x version

```
$winners = $this->Virtualwarehouse->find('all')->contain('User')->where(['Virtualwarehouse.winner !=' => 'null']);
```

For version CakePhp 2.x

```
$this->Virtualwarehouse->recursive = 1;
$winners = $this->Virtualwarehouse->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Virtualwarehouse.winner !=' => 'null')));
print_r($winners);
```

> Make sure in **Virtualwarehouse** model file you have connection with **user** table with **foreign key** column name